# How to compare two dataframes and extract unmatched rows in pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

Hi I have two dataframes. One is parent dataframe and second is incremental dataframe. I just want to extract those records which is present in incremental dataframe but not present in parent dataframe based on the key column.

Example:

Key Column :  `call_id`

parent_dataframe:

```
call_id    call_nm    src
100        QC         Darzalex MM
105        XY         INVOKANA
107        CZ         Simponi  RA
117        NM         Guselkumab PSA
118        YC         STELARA
126        RF         INVOKANA
```

Incremental Dataframe:

```
call_id    call_nm    src
118        YC         STELARA
126        RF         INVOKANA
131        VG         STELARA
135        IJ         Stelara CD
```

Unmatched Dataframe:

```
call_id    call_nm    src
131        VG         STELARA
135        IJ         Stelara CD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left_anti join with Incremenatl coming first. Left_anti checks to see if the values exist in the second df, they then keep values missing in df.

```
Incremental.join(parent_dataframe,on='call_nm', how='left_anti').show()

+-------+-------+----------+
|call_nm|call_id|       src|
+-------+-------+----------+
|     IJ|    135|Stelara CD|
|     VG|    131|   STELARA|
+-------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how to use incremental? I do not see it as a default python method or function.