# PySpark / Snowpark random column name during left anti join problem

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to compare two dataframes, to get new records to be inserted into an incremental table.

I am following previously asked questions, example [How to compare two dataframes and extract unmatched rows in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181011/how-to-compare-two-dataframes-and-extract-unmatched-rows-in-pyspark)

But I'm having this problem, where even though I used the `alias` function, it seems that the output dataframe is having random column names. At least that is what I see in the Snowflake query history.

Sample code:

```py
main = session.table("source")
incremental = session.table("target")

new_customer = (incremental
        .join(main, incremental.customer_id==main.customer_id, "leftanti" )
        .select(main.customer_id.alias("customer_id"))
                        ).show()
```

**Error:**

```
snowflake.snowpark.exceptions.SnowparkSQLException: 1304): 01acd0d6-3201-cee0-0000-6b1502059ff6: 000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7
invalid identifier '"r_tu5s_customer_id".
```

**Query history:**

```sql
SELECT "r_tu5s_customer_id" AS "customer_id" FROM ( SELECT  *  FROM ( SELECT "customer_id" .........
```

Comment: don't you need to select the `customer_id` from the `incremental` df? `.select(incremental.customer_id.alias("customer_id"))` since you are keeping the records from the left df?

Comment: but i would like to get the new records in main_df, which does not yet exist in incremental_df @IslamElbanna

Comment: AFAIK, then you need to switch the two dataframes to set the `main` as the left dataframe to join `main.join(incremental, incremental.customer_id==main.customer_id, "leftanti" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer to be useful for others.

The `leftanti` is similar to the join functionality, but it returns only columns from the **left** DataFrame for non-matched records.

So the solution is just swtiching the two dataframes so you can get the new records in `main` df that don't exist in `incremental` df

```py
main.join(incremental, incremental.customer_id==main.customer_id, "leftanti" )
```